# Does or will Google Glass support wifi direct?

Tags: video-streaming, wifi-direct, google-glass

I know people have managed to do it, but I am really new to Android development so I am stumbling badly. I want to be able to stream camera frames from my google glass to another android device using WiFi Direct protocol. It seems to me that WiFi direct might be the only way to get that kind of data bandwidth. I have looked into WiFi via a router and bluetooth.

I have been studying the Google provided sample code to learn how to do this.

My questions are:

1. Does or will google glass support WiFi Direct?
2. Is WiFi direct a firmware (software) feature or does it require special hardware?

Answer (score 0):

The Explorer edition does not have this feature.

I don't know how much Android functionality Google will put into the consumer release version of Glass.

Answer (score 0):

Wifi Direct is a firmware feature. It can be added to devices with standard wifi, so theoretically Glass will be able to support Wifi Direct (though it currently does not)